# Outlook hangs when I try to load a profile for exchange account

Tags: outlook, outlook-2010, exchange-server-2010

Something corrupted my user profile.

I was running a profile where I connected to a gmail via pop3 and our local exchange server.  One day I killed a process via the debugger during the startup process for Outlook (I am developing an Outlook addin).  Ever since that point, I cannot load Outlook with the exchange server.

I have deleted the original profile and created 2 new profiles where I separated the accounts.  The pop3 one will load every time the pop3 profile is selected.  The exchange one will hang on loading profile, every time the exchange profile is selected.  I get the following message.

```
Cannot open your default e-mail folders.  You must connect to Microsoft Exchange with the current profile before you can synchronize your folders with your Outlook data file (.ost).
```

I've tried running outlook in safe mode, addins disabled, /resetnavpane, outlook reinstalled.  The exchange server is up and running just fine (I can successfully perform the Test Email Autoconfiguration).

Any ideas on what else to try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I followed the steps from http://blog.mpecsinc.ca/2011/06/outlook-error-cannot-open-your-default.html with the addition of a exchange server reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Did you just copy your OST file to a new profile? You cannot do that: OST files are bound to a particular profile.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I tried:

```
outlook.exe /resetnavpane
```

... but it did not help.

I was about to delete the profiles but just then realized that one of the PST file was too big - almost 2 GB. Renaming them fixed the startup problem.